# C# - Changing From MainWindow to Another Page in MVVM Format WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have been trying to figure out how to switch from my `MainWindow.xaml` to a WPF Page in my View folder called `StudentView.xaml` when a button on the MainWindow is clicked.

This is what I have so far...

```
private void ButtonStartQuiz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var window = new View.StudentView();
}
```

All I want is for the MainWindow to switch to the StudentView page when the user clicks the button. I've tried opening the StudentView as a new Window, but I don't want a new window every time the user clicks a button. I've tried googling and looking at other posts, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to implement them. Please help!

Comment: How about making your main window a container like ContentControl, and then set the Content either to the content of your current MainWindow or the StudentView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `button` click then, you can create an `instance` of that `page` and set the `instance` as `content` of your `mainwindow`.

```
     private NavigatingPageName Instance;
     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Instance == null) 
            {
                Instance = new  NavigatingPageName();
            }
            this.Content = Instance;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate from MainPage.xaml to another .xaml use:

```
            NAMEOFYOURCURRENTFRAME.Navigate(typeof(PAGENAME));
```

If you want to navigate from a page which isn´t MainPage.xaml to another .xaml use:

```
        var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        var mainPage = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(PAGETONAVIGATETO));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your `MainWindow.xaml` content's state alive, then use [`Frame + Pages`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754191(v=vs.100).aspx).

Otherwise, use `ContentControl` and use [`ContentTemplateSelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.100).aspx) .